# PHP convert unicode to hex

Tags: php, unicode, hex

An app wants me to insert strings as `text encoded using hex values in proper coding.`, the encoding being `Unicode_No_Compression`

For example, for `Sześć siedem` the correct HEX string is `0053007A0065015B0107002000730069006500640065006D`,
`Źdźbło` = `01790064017A00620142006F`
`String with no special chars` 
=`0053007400720069006E0067002000770069007400680020006E006F0020007300700065006300690061006C002000630068006100720073`

I tried playing with MySQL `HEX()`/`UNHEX()` and `dechex()` PHP, but been unable to figure out how to make this conversion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're essentially looking at the hex version of the UCS-2 encoding, I'm guessing. Therefore:

```
php > echo strtoupper(bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2', 'Źdźbło')));
01790064017A00620142006F
```

Comment: I'm getting slightly different results http://pastebin.com/cw5VuTgM , any idea why?

Comment: Little-endian vs. big-endian issue, which is machine dependent. Try `UCS-2BE` to explicitly use big-endian.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$out = implode("",array_map(function($x) {return sprintf("%04X",ord($x));},str_split($in)));
```

One liner ;)

Comment: Oh... it's not multibyte-safe, is it?

Comment: Neither `ord` nor `str_split` is.